# S3 headphone jack not working properly

Tags: music, headphones, headphone-jack

My Galaxy S3 doesn't play music through an AUX cable, but it works with the headphones that came with it. What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possibly related: [What determines if a phone will accept a microphone in the audio jack - hardware or software?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23381)

Comment: What is on the other side of the aux cable?

Answer (score 0):

You should try another aux cable, it's possible that the TRRS layout doesn't match the phone's jack layout.